# How to iterate through this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I am retrieving information from the GetResponse Email Marketing API and my code returns this data from the array:

```
array(2) {
  ["zAuW"]=>
  object(stdClass)#332 (7) {
    ["optin"]=>
    string(6) "double"
    ["from_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "asw_getresponse_edition"
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
    ["reply_to_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["created_on"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-29 07:27:46"
    ["from_name"]=>
    string(11) "1213456@"
  }
  ["z1Bi"]=>
  object(stdClass)#333 (7) {
    ["optin"]=>
    string(6) "double"
    ["from_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
    ["reply_to_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["created_on"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-29 02:54:51"
    ["from_name"]=>
    string(11) "123456@"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#330 (1) {
  ["zAuW"]=>
  object(stdClass)#334 (7) {
    ["optin"]=>
    string(6) "double"
    ["from_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "asw_getresponse_edition"
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
    ["reply_to_email"]=>
    string(17) "email@gmail.com"
    ["created_on"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-29 07:27:46"
    ["from_name"]=>
    string(11) "123456@"
  }
}
```

Here is the code used to get this data:

```
require_once('GetResponseAPI.class.php');
$api = new GetResponse('YOUR_API_KEY');

// Account
$details = $api->getAccountInfo();
//var_dump($details);

// Campaigns
$campaigns = (array)$api->getCampaigns();
$campaignIDs = array_keys($campaigns);
$campaign = $api->getCampaignByID($campaignIDs[0]);
var_dump($campaigns, $campaign);
```

I would like to know what PHP code could I use to loop through this array and display the information in a dropdown list. I have tried this but it is oviously wrong:

```
$output .= '<select class="asw_select'.$field_class.'" name="'.$this->prefix.'_options['.$id.']" id="'.$this->prefix.'_options['.$id.']">';
foreach($campaign as $key => $value)
    $output .= '<option '.selected($current_mailing_list, $value['id'], false).' id="'.esc_attr($value['id']).'" value="'.$value['id'].'">'. __($value['name'], $this->prefix).'</option>';
$output .= '</select>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `array` of `objects` in your response. So, in your `foreach` loop you should access it's elements like `$value->name` (not as `$value['name']`)

You do not have `id` attribute for your values. So after above correction, `$value->id` will be empty. However the `$key` seems like a unique identifier for me. If this is the case, within your foreach loop you can replace `$value->id` with `$key`

```
$output.= '<select class="asw_select'.$field_class.'" name="'.$this->prefix.'_options['.$id.']" id="'.$this->prefix.'_options['.$id.']">';
foreach($campaign as $key => $value)
    $output .= '<option '.selected($current_mailing_list, $key, false).' id="'.esc_attr($key).'" value="'.$key.'">'. __($value->name, $this->prefix).'</option>';
$output .= '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks @mesutozer, Works great and was exactly what I was after.